# Encryption c# and Cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, encryption

I'm looking for algorithm which not encrypt string with '=' in the end.

Why it that?
I'm using this to store data in the cookie, and the '=' in the string conflicts with the '=' in the cookie.

Anybody has idea?
Thanks..

Comment: Have you had an issue with this or are you thinking it might be an issue? (I'm pretty confident your value will be escaped properly, and won't be a problem)

Answer (score 2):

The `=` at the end of the string is not from the encryption, it's from using base64 encoding.

You can use hexadecimal format instead:

```
string encoded = BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-","");
```

This string contains only the characters 0-9 and A-F, so it won't cause any conflicts.